# Cannot import Room database for use in Android app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-room

I am working on developing an Android app through android studio and I am trying to implement a Room database. I was using https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room for instructions, however I was unable to properly import it in. Trying `import androidx.room.*;` returns `cannot resolve symbol 'room'`. I was unable to find a solution to this issue.

I have tried:

- Using `https://maven.google.com` as a repository
- Using different versions of room
- Using `api` instead of `implementation`

Project Gradle File:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

App Gradle File:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    def room_version = "2.2.6"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
}
```

While gradle syncing, I found that it got stuck on `Download room-runtime-2.2.6.pom...` for 10-15 minutes, and once it completed it showed the warnings:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.6.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.6.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.6.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

Clicking show details did not direct it anywhere

Edit: I resolved the issue by changing the app build.gradle file to use the `https://maven.google.com` repository for both buildscript and allprojects such that my gradle file read

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

as well as

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did your project have been migrated into androidx?

**Migrate an existing project using Android Studio**

> With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, you can migrate an existing project to AndroidX by selecting Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX from the menu bar.
>
> The refactor command makes use of two flags. By default, both of them
> are set to true in your `gradle.properties` file:

```
 android.useAndroidX=true
 android.enableJetifier=true
```

> The Android plugin uses the appropriate
> AndroidX library instead of a Support Library.

source : https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: My gradle.properties file already has the android.useAndroidX and android.enableJetifier flags set to true, should I migrate them anyway?
Edit: Trying to migrate it states "no usages found in project"

Answer (score 0):

**You have to Check Download external annotations for dependencies from setting**

**setp 1 -** Go to *File*

**setp 2 -** Click on *settings*

**setp 3 -** Click on *Build, Execution, Deployment*

**setp 4 -** Click on *Gradle*

**step 5 -** Check *Download external annotations for dependencies*

[image]

Comment: This option is already enabled in my project

Comment: What is the version of your classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2"

Comment: i think room library was not downloaded successfully, check your internet connection then try once again to implement the library

Comment: My classpath is "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2", my internet connection is 100% fine and I've tried on different days

Comment: have you invalidate and restart the android stuido

Comment: Yes I invalidated and restarted android studio, it still gave the errors from the original post